# Noise reduction in time series keeping sharp edges

Tags: python, time-series, noise

In a time series coming from a power meter there is noise from the process as well as from the sensor. To identify steps I want to filter the noise without sacrificing the steepness of the edges.

The ideas was to do a `rolling(window).mean()` => kills the edges or `rolling(window).median()` => but this has issues with harmonic noise if window size needs to be small.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create a reference signal
xrng = 50
sgn = np.zeros(xrng)
sgn[10:xrng//2] = 1
sgn[xrng//2:xrng-10]=0.5

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.plot(sgn, label='raw') 

T=3    # period of the sine like noise (random phase shifts not modeled)
noise1 = (np.random.rand(xrng)-0.5)*0.2          # sensor noise
noise2 = np.sin(np.arange(xrng)*2*np.pi/T)*0.1   # harmonic noise 
sg_n = sgn + noise1 + noise2                     # noised signal 
plt.plot(sg_n, label='noised')

# 1. filter mean (good for hamonic)
mnfltr = np.ones(7)/7             
sg_mn = np.convolve(mnfltr,sg_n, 'same')
plt.plot(sg_mn, label='roll_mean')

# 2. filter median (good for edges)  
median = pd.Series(sg_n).rolling(9).median().shift(-4) 
plt.plot(median, label='roll_med') 

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output look like:
[image: applying mean and median filters to noised signal]

Is there a way to combine both filters to get both benefits or any other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a complete different approach you can reconstruct the stepped signal if the amplitude of the noise doesn't obscure the step size.

Your setup:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xrng = 50
sgn = np.zeros(xrng)
sgn[10:xrng//2] = 1
sgn[xrng//2:xrng-10]=0.5

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.plot(sgn, label='raw') 

T=3    # period of the sine like noise (random phase shifts not modeled)
noise1 = (np.random.rand(xrng)-0.5)*0.2          # sensor noise
noise2 = np.sin(np.arange(xrng)*2*np.pi/T)*0.1   # harmonic noise 
sg_n = sgn + noise1 + noise2                     # noised signal 
plt.plot(sg_n, label='noised')
```

The noisy signal can be digitized

```
bins = np.arange(-.25, 2, .5)
plt.plot((np.digitize(sg_n, bins)-1)/2, '.', markersize=8, label='reconstructed from noiced')
plt.legend();
```

Result:

[image: reconstructed signal]

Comment: thank you for this suggestion. The constraint you raised is partly violated. Nevertheless, it can be useful for certain segments of the time series.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know when the steps occures nor their amplitude, you could use [Rupture](https://centre-borelli.github.io/ruptures-docs/) package to determine windows where the signal is stable. Then for each stable window, you compute the mean and attribute it.

```
# building rupture to find the rupture points
algo = rpt.Pelt(model="rbf").fit(sg_n)
result = algo.predict(pen=2)

# Plot ruptures results
rpt.display(sg_n, result)

# smoothing signal piecewise
start_pt = 0
smoothed = []
for i in result:
    smoothed.append(np.tile(np.mean(sg_n[start_pt:i]), i-start_pt))
    start_pt = i
smoothed = np.hstack(smoothed)

# adding smoothed signal to ruptures plot
plt.plot(smoothed, '.', markersize=8, label='reconstructed from noised')
plt.legend()
```

Here is the result:

[image: Raw, noisy and smoothed data with the ruptures slicing results represented by the background color]